# Como selecionar mudar <a> de acordo com <select> com PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal estou tentando alterar,o link da tag , que esta dentro de um  quando o usuario escolher umas das opções do . Estou tentando fazer essa alteração com PHP. Mas já fiz varias maneiras e não funcionou. Alguem pode me sugerir alguma solução?

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="metrica">Escolha a Métrica Desejada:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="metrica" id="metrica">
                <option name="host" value="1">Host</option>
                <option name="DG" value="2">Distância Geográfica</option>
                <option name="custo"value="3">Custo</option>


            </select>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Selecione a métrica do cálculo</small>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <?php
            //$mt = isset($_GET['metrica']) ? $_GET['metrica']:0;
            $ht = isset($_GET['host']) ? $_GET['host']:0;
            $dg = isset($_GET['DG'])? $_GET['DG']:0;
            $ct = isset($_GET['custo'])? $_GET['custo']:0;
            if($ht):?>
            <a href='principal.html'>Escolher cidades</a>;
            <?php
            elseif($dg):
            ?>
            <a href='principal.1.html'>Escolher cidades</a>;
            <?php
            elseif($ct):
            ?>
            <a href='principal.2.html'>Escolher cidades</a>
            <?php
            endif;
            ?>  
            </button>

            <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </div>


        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo? Quando selecionar `Host` o `href` deve ser `principal.html` e assim por diante? Não precisa mudar o texto? $off: Porque colocou o `a` dentro do `button`? Não me parece ideal...

Comment: @LipESprY isso mesmo.quando for "host" o href de ser principal.html, se for "Distancia demografica" ele irá principal.1.html e se ele escolher o "custo", ele irá para principal.2.html.

Comment: @LipESprY sobre a tag <a> é um habito meu fazer assim! Talvez um mal habito.

Comment: Cada doido com sua mania (gambi)! Já que o botão não vai executar nenhuma ação, o ideal é que não use-o. Se quer que seu link tenha aparência de um botão, faça-o parecer um botão! 

Comment: Seu código está errado. Além de ser errado usar <a> dentro de <button>, você deveria pegar o valor do select no GET, e não da option. Vc deve pegar o valor de `name="metrica"`, que será o valor do option selecionado.

Comment: Mas eu não entendo pq meu if está dando erro. Retirei o button o nenhum texto aparece.

Comment: @Sam fiz a alteração que mencionou, agora esta aparecendo o o texto, mas o href mantém o mesmo,'principal.html', para todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, deve-se entender que o PHP roda no servidor. Logo, toda vez que o usuário alterar o `select`, você teria que submeter um formulário com `action` para a mesma página, capturar o valor do `select` e então renderizar o seu link `a` com o `href` desejado.

Acontece que isso é muita volta para fazer algo simples. Repare: você tem três opções no seu `select`. E todos os valores são estáticos. Não tem lógica você dar toda essa volta. Simplesmente faça com o JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('metrica').addEventListener(
    'change',
    function(){
        document.getElementById('link-cidade').setAttribute('href', this.value);
    },
    false
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="metrica">Escolha a Métrica Desejada:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="metrica" id="metrica">
            <option name="host" value="principal.html">Host</option>
            <option name="DG" value="principal.1.html">Distância Geográfica</option>
            <option name="custo"value="principal.2.html">Custo</option>


        </select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Selecione a métrica do cálculo</small>

        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">-->
            <a id="link-cidade" href="principal.html">Escolher cidades</a>
        <!--</button>-->

        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
    // código no snippet
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

1) Adicionei um `id="link-a"` ao seu link `a`;

2) Adicionei um [eventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) no seu `select` que já está com ID `metrica` que captura o evento `change` e define o atributo `href` do seu link;

3) Adicionei os links devidamente aos `value` dos `option`. Utilizar os números iria delegar mais uma volta desnecessária: criar uma condição (switch) retornando certo link para certo número.

PS: comentei as tags `button`. Se você se sente melhor utilizando-o, só descomentar. ‍♂️

Comment: Cara muito obrigado! Nunca tinha visto dessa maneira, para essa maneira do javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com Jquery, quando selecionar algo no campo métrica, alterar o endereço do link. Precisa apenas colocar um ID nele. Segue um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#metrica").change(function () {
    switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
         $("#link").attr("href", "principal.html");
        break;
    case "2":
         $("#link").attr("href", "principal1.html");
   break;
 case "3":
         $("#link").attr("href", "principal2.html");
   break;  
 } 
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="metrica">Escolha a Métrica Desejada:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="metrica" id="metrica">
                <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                <option name="host" value="1">Host</option>
                <option name="DG" value="2">Distância Geográfica</option>
                <option name="custo"value="3">Custo</option>


            </select>
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Selecione a métrica do cálculo</small>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <a id="link" href="">Escolher cidades</a>;
            </button>
            <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </div>


        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#metrica").change(function () {
  switch (this.value) {
  case "1":
    $("#link").attr("href", "principal.html");
   break;
  case "2":
    $("#link").attr("href", "principal1.html");
    break;
  case "3":
    $("#link").attr("href", "principal2.html");
    break;  
  } 
   });
 });
 </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: agradeço. Mas já tentei assim, não deu certo. Coloquei na head, depois do footer e até em arquivos separados e nada.

Comment: Eu editei a resposta. Adicionando o script antes de fechar a tag body ele funciona